# TypeError: at / 'module' object is not callable in Python rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have simple django_restframework project but I got an error in below. I don't know root cause why it shows. Am I doing wrong somewhere?

This is my serializer
**StorySerializer.py:**

```
from .models import Category, Story
from rest_framework import serializers

class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.id')
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['category', 'name', 'author', 'url', 'content']
```

This is my view
**Views.py**

```
class StoryviewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed stories (or edited)
    """

    queryset = models.Story.objects.all().order_by('-public_day')
    serializer_class = StorySerializer

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

And urls
**urls.py**

```
...
from stories import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'stories', views.StoryviewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    ........
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .....
    'rest_framework',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS' : 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE' : 5,
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

But when I call the API and I got an error
**Error**

```
> Internal Server Error: /api/stories/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 55, in inner
>     response = get_response(request)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 197, in _get_response
>     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
> line 56, in wrapper_view
>     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py",
> line 125, in view
>     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 509, in dispatch
>     response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 469, in handle_exception
>     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
>     raise exc   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
> line 506, in dispatch
>     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py",
> line 42, in list
>     serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)   File "D:\Projects\Python\Module_3\MyNews\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py",
> line 110, in get_serializer
>     return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable [10/Dec/2023 08:31:51] "GET /api/stories/
> HTTP/1.1" 500 108765
```

Please! help me to Fix it....

Thanks! in Advance.....

Comment: The api /api work correct but when I call api/stories I got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `StorySerializer.py`,if imports are correct then the field `category = serializers.CharField(source='category.id')` might be causing error if category is a foreign key & Category is another model in story model. you might want to use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead of `serializers.CharField`

```py
class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ['category', 'name', 'author', 'url', 'content']
```

This will represent the category foreign key as a primary key related field. If category is not a foreign key then original argument is correct.

Also make sure that `StorySerializer` is correctly imported at the top in `views.py`

```py
from .StorySerializer import StorySerializer
```

This assumes that `StorySerializer` is defined in a file named StorySerializer.py in the same directory as your `views.py` file

That should be all!

Comment: Thanks @Siddhart Sutar, it's only fixed from .StorySerializer import StorySerializer  and it's worked ok now. Many thanks